# Homestead 3.3 - no databases found - app works fine

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead

After upgrading from homestead 3.0 to 3.3, I lost my database tables. When I open Sequel Pro and connect to homestead, I only get two databases, "homestead" and "sys". My apps works fine, but I cannot find the databases...

[image: No databases found. But app works fine]

[image: How I connect]

On port `3306`:

[image: On port 3306]

Comment: Cant. Updated with image

Comment: Can you access from `vagrant ssh`? `mysql -uhomestead -psecret`?

Comment: What database your app uses? The one you can't access?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you update vagrant box, you'd have to expect losing your databases. Homestead doesn't save them, nor does vagrant.

Working solution would be dumping the database before update.

On a sidenote. Until you destroy box, the database will persist because you are still employing the old version.